# SetThreadContext x64 volatile registers

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, x86-64, cpu-registers

I have a problem with SetThreadContext.
I can't change any of volatile registers (table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx)).

```
data.context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
SuspendThread(hThread);

GetThreadContext(hThread, &data.context);

...

CONTEXT* ctx = &data.context;
ctx->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER;

ctx->Rax = (DWORD64)0x1000;
ctx->Rcx = (DWORD64)-1;
ctx->Rip = (DWORD64)allocatedMemory;
ctx->R10 = (DWORD64)0x12345678;
ctx->Rbp = (DWORD64)0xFFFFFFFF;
SetThreadContext(hThread, ctx);

ResumeThread(hThread);
```

That code changes Rip and Rbp registers because they are non-volatile.
GetLastError returning 0.
Thread opened with THREAD_SET_CONTEXT | THREAD_GET_CONTEXT | THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME | THREAD_SET_INFORMATION rights.

Why i can't change volatile registers in x64 app? In x86 application i could change any register (it was does not matter volatile or not).

P.S. Yes, i tried to call SetThreadContext with ctx->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;

Comment: Are you sure they aren't getting set at all? What if they *are* getting set, but then are changed before you check them?

Comment: i placing breakpoint on allocatedMemory address. And when it works i see only non-volatile registers are changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 64 bit windows SetThreadContext sets the non-volatile registers only. (see PspGetSetContextInternal at /base/ntos/ps/amd64/psctxamd64.c in the WRK) [1](http://gate.upm.ro/os/LABs/Windows_OS_Internals_Curriculum_Resource_Kit-ACADEMIC/WindowsResearchKernel-WRK/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ps/amd64/psctxamd64.c)

The registers that sets are: Rbx, Rsp, Rbp, Rsi, Rdi, R12-R15, Xmm6-Xmm15 only.